# UIPickerView not displaying data

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, uipickerview

I've followed a couple youtube tutorials as well as advice on here but I can't seem to get my UIPickerView to display its data.  I'm populating the picker using three arrays and I thought I've implemented the code correctly but obviously something is wrong.  The picker displays the number of elements correctly, the problem is that they are all displayed as '?'

I've tried setting the picker's delegate to self, but that didn't work either.  Thanks in advance.

Here's my .h file:

```
@interface BACcalcViewController : UIViewController<UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate>
@property(strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPickerView *personInfoPicker;
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSArray *heightsArray;
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSArray *weightsArray;
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSArray *timeArray;
@end
```

Here's my .m file:

```
@interface BACcalcViewController () <UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate>

@end

@implementation BACcalcViewController


@synthesize personInfoPicker, heightsArray, weightsArray, timeArray;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

[super viewDidLoad];

heightsArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                         @"5ft 0in",
                         @"5ft 1in",
                         @"5ft 2in",
                         @"5ft 3in",
                         @"5ft 4in",
                         @"5ft 5in",
                         @"5ft 6in",
                         @"5ft 7in",
                         @"5ft 8in",
                         @"5ft 9in",
                         @"5ft 10in",
                         @"5ft 11in",
                         @"6ft 1in",
                         @"6ft 2in",
                         @"6ft 3in",
                         @"6ft 4in",
                         @"6ft 5in",
                         @"6ft 6in",
                         @"6ft 7in",
                         @"6ft 8in",
                         nil];

weightsArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                     @"100",
                     @"110",
                     @"120",
                     @"130",
                     @"140",
                     @"150",
                     @"160",
                     @"170",
                     @"180",
                     @"190",
                     @"200",
                     @"210",
                     @"220",
                     @"230",
                     @"240",
                     @"250",
                     @"260",
                     nil];


timeArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
             @"1",
             @"2",
             @"3",
             @"4",
             @"5",
             @"6",
             nil];
}



- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)personInfoPicker
{
    return 3;
}


- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)personInfoPicker numberOfRowsInComponent: (NSInteger)component
{
    if (component == 0) 
        return [heightsArray count];
    else if (component == 1)
        return [weightsArray count];
    else
        return [timeArray count];
}

- (NSString *)pickerview:(UIPickerView *)personInfoPicker titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{    
    if (component == 0)
        return [heightsArray objectAtIndex:row];
    else if (component == 1)
        return [weightsArray objectAtIndex:row];
    else
        return [timeArray objectAtIndex:row];
}
@end
```

Comment: have you set the delegate and datasource of your UIPickerView to File Owner ?

Comment: Yep, I hooked up all the IB parts in storyboard just like the youtube videos did.

Comment: then try @Durgaprasad's answer once it can help

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to set picker view's `dataSource` and call `reloadAllComponents` after populating arrays.

```
self.personInfoPicker.delegate = self;
self.personInfoPicker.dataSource = self;
[self.personInfoPicker reloadAllComponents];
```

Comment: You should set `delegate` and `dataSource` first, then call `reloadAllComponents`. So you got the code right, just not the order.

Comment: Should I set the data source with: personInfoPicker.dataSource = self;

Comment: Why don't you just try? I have updated my answer with the exact code you need.

Comment: I know, it didn't work for me but I'll mark it because it will probably work for somebody else.  There must be something else wrong with my program, but thanks for your input.

Answer (score 2):

try initialising all three arrarys in init method.

Answer (score 2):

can you try this below code.

```
`NSMutableArray *_month_ary=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"01",@"02",@"03",@"04",@"05",@"06",@"07",@"08",@"09",@"10",@"11",@"12", nil];
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView;
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{


    if ([pickerView isEqual:_month_picker_view]) {
        return [_month_ary count];
    }
    return 0;
}
-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{


    if ([pickerView isEqual:_month_picker_view])
    {
        return [_month_ary objectAtIndex:row];
    }
    return nil;
}
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{


    if ([pickerView isEqual:_month_picker_view]) {
        _Pay_Month_txt.text=[_month_ary objectAtIndex:row];
        deal_cridit_card_month_str = [_month_ary objectAtIndex:row];
    }
}`
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine. Just need to change in object of "pickerView" name in method.

Replace

```
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)personInfoPicker numberOfRowsInComponent: (NSInteger)component
```

By,

```
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView numberOfRowsInComponent: (NSInteger)component
```

And,

```
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)personInfoPicker numberOfRowsInComponent: (NSInteger)component
```

By,

```
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView numberOfRowsInComponent: (NSInteger)component
```

Because `personInfoPicker` is the object of `PickerView` you used already in .h file, So it'll conflict while loading data for `pickerView`.

Hopefully, it'll help you.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

i Think your code is absolutely correct and you set `datasource` and `delegate` as well but you forget to reload `uipickerview` so in last of `viewdidload` reload `pickerview` that solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

I´ve copied your initial code and found your bug now. There is a typo in the delegate method name

instead of

```
- (NSString *)pickerview:(UIPickerView *)personInfoPicker titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
```

it must be

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)personInfoPicker titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
```

If you write pickerview it will declare a new method in your class which will never be called. So simple but anoying anyway :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you did't allocated the array used as data source of picker e.g

```
 NSMutableArray *_month_ary=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"01",@"02",@"03",@"04",@"05",@"06",@"07",@"08",@"09",@"10",@"11",@"12", nil];
```